# how to make a viewmodel singleton instance?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

The idea is to do this. I have a login page that has successfully passed the Username.text value into a text box in the main window.

Now I need this username.text value in the main window to be passed on to textboxes in all child pages. I am doing this so that the program will know which user is logging in and can log who is making what changes to the database.

One-way Databinging from what i know is the best way of doing this but, i understand i need to create a viewmodel singleton instance for it to work between the MainWindow, and the child pages.

this is what I am failing to do. this code works fine in the same page.

```
    <TextBox x:Name="username" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=alias, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11"/>

<TextBox x:Name="alias" Margin="186,64,0,0" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11" ></TextBox>
```

in different pages though, nothing.

Code for MainWindow

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="Masca.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
Title="Masca Database Admin" Height="800" Width="1280" IsTitleVisible="True"
LogoData="F1 M 24.9015,43.0378L 25.0963,43.4298C 26.1685,49.5853 31.5377,54.2651 38,54.2651C 44.4623,54.2651 49.8315,49.5854 50.9037,43.4299L 51.0985,43.0379C 51.0985,40.7643 52.6921,39.2955 54.9656,39.2955C 56.9428,39.2955 58.1863,41.1792 58.5833,43.0379C 57.6384,52.7654 47.9756,61.75 38,61.75C 28.0244,61.75 18.3616,52.7654 17.4167,43.0378C 17.8137,41.1792 19.0572,39.2954 21.0344,39.2954C 23.3079,39.2954 24.9015,40.7643 24.9015,43.0378 Z M 26.7727,20.5833C 29.8731,20.5833 32.3864,23.0966 32.3864,26.197C 32.3864,29.2973 29.8731,31.8106 26.7727,31.8106C 23.6724,31.8106 21.1591,29.2973 21.1591,26.197C 21.1591,23.0966 23.6724,20.5833 26.7727,20.5833 Z M 49.2273,20.5833C 52.3276,20.5833 54.8409,23.0966 54.8409,26.197C 54.8409,29.2973 52.3276,31.8106 49.2273,31.8106C 46.127,31.8106 43.6136,29.2973 43.6136,26.197C 43.6136,23.0966 46.127,20.5833 49.2273,20.5833 Z"          
ContentSource="/Pages/Home.xaml">

    <Window.DataContext>
<TextBox x:Name="username" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=alias, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11"/>
```

Code for child page

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Masca.Mail.Configuration"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1280">
```

```
<TextBox x:Name="alias" Margin="186,64,0,0" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11" ></TextBox>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: did you look for singleton implementation in google?

Comment: I haven't tried that particular word combination yet. Doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the Cinch MVVM framework that uses MEF to instantiate / inject ViewModels. Making a Singleton ViewModel is really easy using the proper export attribute.

Check the site of the project. I encourage you to use it.

http://cinch.codeplex.com/

Comment: In Cinch this is possible via     [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM and the goal is to share data between viewmodels, what you need is a `Mediator`/`EventAggregator`. Your MainViewModel can post data onto Mediator once the login is successful, and all other ViewModel can listen for this message and update their corresponding properties for UserName.

More reading on these:

EventAggregator: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2011/01/15/Using-the-Prism-40-Event-Aggregator.aspx

Mediator: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/mediator-v2-for-mvvm-wpf-and-silverlight-applications/

However, if you really want to make your ViewModel a singleton and have that as `DataContext` for all views, you want to read this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) page about implementing Singleton in C#.